# In iostat, why are kB_wrtn/s and kB_wrtn the same?

Tags: linux-mint, iostat, sysstat

/dev/sdc is a SATA hard drive. Do the kB_read and kB_wrtn fields sometimes, in some situations, show total counts? Here it seems to be just the same as the per second value.

- Linux kernel 5.4.0-26-generic.
- sysstat version 12.2.0

`iostat -dz 1`

```
Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdc              40.00         0.00        21.00         0.00          0         21          0


Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
dm-0              6.00         0.00        24.00         0.00          0         24          0
sdc              42.00         0.00        42.50         0.00          0         42          0


Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
dm-0              5.00         0.00        20.00         0.00          0         20          0
sdc              43.00         0.00        36.00         0.00          0         36          0


Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdc              48.00         0.00        25.00         0.00          0         25          0


Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdc              36.00         0.00        18.50         0.00          0         18          0


Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdc              40.00         0.00        21.00         0.00          0         21          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kB_wrtn` is the total amount written **during the iostat update interval**. I suppose you used an interval of one second to generate the output in your question, which has the effect that `kB_wrtn/sec` is the same. Try a different interval to see the difference.

Comment: Yes I used interval 1 second. That makes a lot of sense.Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The `kB_wrtn` column represents the total number of kilobytes written to the disk since the start of the `iostat` command, whereas `kB_wrtn/s` column represents the number of kilobytes written to the disk per second over the last reporting interval.

So, if you are generating the `iostat` results per second, the maximum value of `kB_wrtn` will keep increasing over time as more and more data is written to the disk. On the other hand, the maximum value of `kB_wrtn/s` will only reflect the maximum write rate observed during a single reporting interval.

For example, suppose the reporting interval is set to 1 second and during one interval, 1 GB of data is written to the disk. Then, the maximum value of `kB_wrtn` will increase by 1 GB, while the maximum value of `kB_wrtn/s` will only be 1024 (assuming no other writes were performed during that interval).

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer? It makes sense, explains the problem and looks to be correct. Yours contradicts and doesn't make sense. Clearly the maximum value of kB_wrtn doesn't always increase. You should probably pick a value other than one second for your example. If a gigabyte is written in one second why would kB_wrtn/s be 1024?